# How to get the actual viewport of a mobile device that has a meta viewport size?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

Most mobile pages are served with meta viewport sizes, e.g.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>` Which will simulate 320px on width for iphone backward compatibility reasons...

but when i check via javascript `window.screen.availWidth` running on and android emulator for example, i get some value like `720`, but a `320px` image covers the whole screen.

How to i get the actual width being used by the document?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested on my Android emulator, and it returns the wrong value when the page is loaded first time. I used this trick to get the right value.

```
setTimeout("your javascript function",200);
```

I executed my function after 200ms and I got the right width and height. I didn't try any other duration than 200ms so you might be able to get the right value in shorter time.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct, even 1 would do. It just have to leave the page rendering flow. It will not work with anything that uses document.write for example... and since my question is for an Ad platform, those damn things still live on document.write. I will upvote and wait to see if anyone knows of a during-render solution, if not i will accept this one. It is weird because other meta tags trigger, such as encoding... your document.write-using script may have utf8 chars if you have the meta before the script tag...